# how to federate SSO OpenDNS with Azure AD

Tags: azure

We are being redirected properly to Azure however it seems we are getting a bad request and I am unable to find out what is expected to allow redirection and sending of a proper SAML response to the applicaiton.

federate OpenDNS with AAD but authentication got  the following error:

Sign In
Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
We received a bad request.

Additional technical information:
Correlation ID: dc09d5a5-37c1-4820-ac18-b7e82517b944
Timestamp: 2017-06-28 17:14:21Z
AADSTS90023: One AuthnContextClassRef or AuthnContextDeclRef entry is expected in RequestedAuthnContext.

Answer (score 2):

According to the error, your SAML request has specified `RequestedAuthnContext`, but has not specified the expected value inside it. Quoting from docs:

> The RequestedAuthnContext element specifies the desired authentication
>   methods. It is optional in AuthnRequest elements sent to Azure AD.
>   **Azure AD supports only one AuthnContextClassRef value:
>   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password.**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-single-sign-on-protocol-reference#authnrequest